# Date conversion query in SQL using STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In my table, there is a date column i.e. ORDER DATE which is in dd-mm-yyyy format, and the datatype of this date column is text. Now, I want to convert the format from yyyy-mm-dd. But the date format is not changing at all. Trying to use STR_TO_DATE but the year in the dates are coming as 2020 only. Not sure how to fix it or if there is a better way to convert the date in MySQL.

For example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('14-09-2017','%d-%m-%y') AS DATE;
Result coming as 2020-09-14
```

Or suppose

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20-MAR-2018','%d-%b-%y') AS DATE;
Result coming as 2020-03-20
```

day and month are coming properly but the year is not coming. Kindly help how to get convert the date format correctly.

Comment: check [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) `%Y` for four-digit year

Comment: "*the datatype of this date column is text.*" - **never** store date values as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your command like this below and you will get the answer:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('14-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y') AS DATE;

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) for more info about the commands.

Comment: Appreciate the help issue resolved. Is there any way I can change the datatype of this date '14-09-2017' which is in text type and format is like this dd-mm-yyyy? If it is there then I will change the datatype of that date column and will use it as a date column.